# Better way to refer to a purchase paid in installments?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to translate the phrase "Pagar a meses sin intereses" from spanish.
I have searched for translations and the most convincing for me is "to pay in installments" but I'm not sure it expresses the same concept, and don't know if it's the most commonly used in english. I'm looking for a phrase or term that is commonplace and accurate.

For non-spanish speakers:
If you make a purchase with a credit card and instead of paying the full amount immediately, you pay amount/number_of_months without incurring any interest from your bank.

Edit - Examples in a sentence:
Compré mi computadora a 12 meses sin intereses.
¿Puedo pagar a meses (sin intereses)?

More clarification:
I'm from Mexico and this type of purchase is very common here. You pay by credit card and the total amount is split and each fraction paid monthly. In some other Latin American countries it's called "pagar en cuotas". It is different from a loan because there's no interest incurred. I don't want a precise legal term, but rather the most common way to refer to this type of payment, preferably a simple phrase that isn't an explanation in itself but a concept.

Comment: What is the rest of the sentence you are trying to use this phrase in? or is it just the phrase?

Comment: It's more a matter of knowing the actual and correct translation of the term.

Comment: A similar thing to this would be if someone takes out a personal loan, or a car loan - so long as they pay the agreed upon amount each month the total cost of the loan doesn't change. However, this monthly payment amount already takes into account the interest/fees that would be charged over the agreed upon time frame. I am not sure of a case (maybe [layaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layaway) but those payments are to a store and you don'T get the object until you pay in full) where there is not interest or fee paid when a bank is fronting money.

Comment: If you say *pay in/by instalments*, that's perfectly idiomatic but it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with credit cards. It sounds as though that's important, in which case you can say (*pay by credit card in x interest-free instalments*). Unless credit cards work very differently where you are, even if the store charges the instalments to the card without any interest, the customer could still end up paying interest under the credit card agreement - so you might need to be careful if this is contractual and/or is in a highly regulated area.

Comment: interest-free credit

Comment: Buying on credit is a lot like drinking. It’s fine in moderation, but too much can bring you to an undesirable and disreputable state. There are many subtleties, since in practice the interest on a “zero interest rate loan” is simply added to the purchase price. Most buyers understand this at some level, but collude psychologically with the seller, in order to feel that they are “getting a good deal”. Without the context for the original phrase, it’s hard to give you an expression that a native speaker would use.  Some terms would sound either ironic or hopelessly naive.

Comment: Your examples both include the words _sin intereses_, once witout brackets and once with. Would you say these words when asking for the payment details or have you included them as clarification for non-Mexicans?

Comment: The one with brackets is meant to show you may or may not say "intereses" to shorten the phrase. Most of the time in Mexico paying this way implies no interest will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

After posting the same question on *Money and Financing* as suggested, surprisingly there isn't ONE term used for it. It varies even for different stores, apparently. This is really interesting to me since in Mexico the *Meses sin intereses* term in generalized completely. Sometimes shortened to just *meses* or *MSI*. It seems it is not only a language issue, but also cultural, and I did not expect that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want "interest-free". (In this sense "free" means "without", as in "gluten-free").

Example 1:

- Compré mi computadora a 12 meses sin intereses.
- I bought my computer in 12 months, interest-free.

Example 2:

- ¿Puedo pagar a meses (sin intereses)?
- Can I pay monthly, interest-free?

If you want a precise term for a legally equivalent transaction, then it really depends on what the terms of the contract are. There are numerous schemes, such as hire-purchase, personal-contract-hire, and so forth, which may have a different bundle of rights and obligations.

Comment: If you want the precise term, it *might* be better to ask over on Money and Finance.

Comment: I don't think that 'I **bought** my computer **in** 12 months' would be understood by a typical English speaker in the way that is intended here.

Comment: I agree with @jsw29, the use of **in** would be a bit confusing.

Comment: How about “bought *over* twelve months”?

Comment: @jsw29 I agree "over" would be more idiomatic but I don't agree that "in" would not be understood. Source: Me, a native English speaker.

Comment: Most people do not conceptualise buying as something that takes place over a long period of time; it is paying for one's purchases that is stretched over time in these arrangements. One is thus likely to say that one bought one's computer in, say, March 2018, even if the payments were stretched between March 2018 and February 2019.